# Meaning of ${#variable[@]}

Tags: bash, shell

Recently, I've been starting work about shell scripting.

When I was reading some script, suddenly that variable appeared.

```
${#variable[@]}
```

It looks like array variable but I don't know exactly what it is.
What is that? and What's the meaning of this syntax?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being unable to RTFM.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain more specifically? I don't know what are you talking about expecailly 'it is about being unable to RTFM' because English is my second language.

Comment: A web search might help.

Comment: "RTFM" means "read the fine manual".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bash, that gives you the number of elements in an array.  From the [Arrays section in Bash's documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

> `${#name[subscript]}` expands to the length of `${name[subscript]}`. If `subscript` is `‘@’` or `‘*’`, the expansion is the number of elements in the array.